# Using Zurb Foundation/ Bootstrap with Code Igniter PHP Project

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have inherited a project developed on codeigniter and plan to make it responsive. Can using zurb foundation Css responsive framework worth it. Also I have been told that as both CI and Zurb have different file structures it might not work. Is it true? Also any suggestions between zurb or bootstrap.
PS: Feel free to suggest alternatives than Zurb/Bootstap etc or any other advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both Zurb Foundation and Twitter Bootstrap with Codeigniter (or any PHP frameworks). You just need to link the correct CSS file to your page. The choice between these 2 is entirely dependent on what all CSS features you want. Please check their respective websites to find the components that they provide. I personally think Bootstrap has more number of components.